# Running Flutter on a Genymotion machine using VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, genymotion

I'm using VS Code as my IDE for `Flutter` and I'm trying to run my app in a `Genymotion` machine. How can I do that? The machine doesn't appear in VS Code bottom bar in the Devices section.

**N.B**:

> I'm not looking for any solutions regarding Android emulators or Android Studio, only VS Code with Genymotion.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so after an hour or so of searching I found out the solution. It's entirely the same as the approach of using `Genymotion` in `Android Studio`. The only difference is you don't need to install a plugin for `VS Code`. However, in my case, it was a bug in `Genymotion` it self. I was using v3.0.1 which had some incompatibility bug with `Android SDK 28` and this was the reason why the `Genymotion` machine did not show up as a device in VS Code, because this latter relies on `Android SDK` to determine what are the devices that run Android.

**The solution for me was simply upgrading my `Genymotion` to v3.0.2 which fixed the incompatibility with `Android SDK 28`.**

In case anyone runs into this problem in the future and this doesn't work, make sure that your `Genymotion ADB` settings use the `Android SDK` installed in your machine by `Android Studio` and not the one shipped with `Genymotion` itself.